# Understanding Multi-Row Subqueries in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle

I executed a SQL statement and come across a mess. I am not able to understand how this output is coming.
My employee table is: Emp_Id is primary key and dept_no is a foreign key to some other table.

```
EMP_ID     EMP_NAME             DEPT_NO    MGR_NAME      MGR_NO
---------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- -----------
       111 Anish                       121 Tanuj            1123
       112 Aman                        122 Jasmeet          1234
      1123 Tanuj                       122 Vipul             122
      1234 Jasmeet                     122 Anish             111
       122 Vipul                       123 Aman              112
       100 Chetan                      123 Anoop             666
       101 Antal                           Aman
      1011 Anjali                      126
      1111 Angelina                    127
```

My dep1 table is:

```
   DEPT_ID DEPT_NAME
---------- -------------
       121 CSE
       122 ECE
       123 MEC
```

And the two tables are not linked at all.

The SQL Query is:

```
SQL> select emp_name 
     from employee 
     where dept_no IN (select dept_no from dep1 where dept_name='MEC');
```

And the output is:

```
EMP_NAME 
-------------------- 
Anish 
Aman
Tanuj 
Jasmeet 
Vipul 
Chetan 
Anjali 
Angelina  
8 rows selected.
```

And if I change the where condition to dept_name='me' it returns no rows.
Can someone explain why the execution is not generating an error since dept_no is not the column of dep1 table. And how the output is being generated.

Comment: First of all why should it return 8 rows instead of 2 in your first query. Seems the NULL value is left out. Please post the table structure and sample inserts

Comment: Can you please post your original query? It will give us more insights? I guess it should either be a typo or you should have some quotes

Answer (score 0):

As from your query,

```
..where dept_no IN (select dept_no ...); -- it is similar as using EXISTS
```

The condition `EXISTS` is being done here: ( oracle won't return error for EXISTS clause).

```
CREATE TABLE my_test(ID INT);
CREATE TABLE my_new_test ( new_ID INT);
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR 
select * from my_test where id in( select id from my_new_test);

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
| Id  | Operation           | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |             |     1 |    13 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
|*  1 |  FILTER             |             |       |       |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | MY_TEST     |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
|*  3 |   FILTER            |             |       |       |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| MY_NEW_TEST |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

   1 - filter( EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "MY_NEW_TEST" "MY_NEW_TEST" WHERE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
              :B1=:B2))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   3 - filter(:B1=:B2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

Note                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
-----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

If you execute the plan for the valid columns , here ( new_id):
then normal access is done:

```
  1 - ACCESS("ID"="NEW_ID")
```

And will cause and error for the following:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR 
select * from my_test where id in( select some_thing from my_new_test);
```

`SQL Error: ORA-00904: "SOME_THING": invalid identifier`

Answer (score 0):

if you run this query:

```
 select emp_name 
 from employee 
 where dept_no IN (select t.dept_no from dep1 t where dept_name='MEC');
```

you will see the error there for in your query dept_no comes from employee table (not from dep1 table)and when dept_no is null ,no result will be come back from it and if you change your dept_name to something which is not in dep1 table it is clear that your dep1 table returns nothing and then dept_no cant be in nothing.

Comment: That is what I wanted to know. How is it taking the dept_no from the employee table. I have used the dept_no in a sub query which will be treated as a separate query. It should give an error since dept_no is not a column of dep1 table

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer it.

Oracle uses optimizer to decide the explain plan. Oracle may rewrite your query as it likes and thinks which one is better. And in and exists are interchangeable and performance depend on different things. (exists ends in full table scan and in uses index).

Let me take your case. Below is the explain plan for your query

```
Plan hash value: 3333342911

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |            |     9 |   225 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER             |            |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | EMPLOYEE   |     9 |   225 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   FILTER            |            |       |       |            |          |
|*  4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| DEPARTMENT |     1 |    12 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

1 - filter( EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "DEPARTMENT" "DEPARTMENT" WHERE 
          :B1=:B2 AND "DEPT_NAME"='MEC'))
3 - filter(:B1=:B2)
4 - filter("DEPT_NAME"='MEC')

Note
-----
- dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

This explain plan clearly shows that the query is re-written to use exists and it is equivalent to

```
select emp_name from employee where exists (select 0 from department where dept_name = 'MEC' and dept_no = dept_no);
```

The above query is a valid query and you are getting the right results.

Bind variables are nothing but dept_no (joining column).

Refer this [IN vs EXISTS in oracle](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3a%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:953229842074) link to know more about in and exists.

Your explain plan is completely different if you use the correct column name. Below is the query and explain plan

Query:

```
select emp_name from employee where dept_no IN (select dept_id from department where dept_name='MEC');
```

Explain Plan:

```
Plan hash value: 3817251802

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |            |     2 |   100 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN SEMI    |            |     2 |   100 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMPLOYEE   |     9 |   225 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| DEPARTMENT |     1 |    25 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

1 - access("DEPT_NO"="DEPT_ID")
3 - filter("DEPT_NAME"='MEC')

Note
-----
- dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

Oracle thinks it is better to use the filter and hash join to get the required details.

This behaviour depends on the oracle query parser and optimizer.

Answer (score -1):

How about a join?

```
select a.emp_name
  from employee a
  join dep1 b
    on a.dept_no = b.dept_id
 where b.dept_name = 'MEC'
```

Comment: This is no way an answer to OP's question